# Postdoctoral application asks about 'ability to assess resource requirements'

Tags: application, postdocs

I'm in the process of applying for a postdoctoral arts position in the UK, and the application asks me to address my 'ability to assess resource requirements and use resources effectively'. In the context of an arts position, does anyone have any clear idea what they expect me to discuss here?

Comment: Sounds like a fancy way of saying "resource management." Staying on budget and not wasting materials, basically.

Comment: @Compass Can you please convert your comment into an answer so that I can vote for it?

Comment: @jakebeal Given the time spread, I've so, under the assumption that Compass isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a fairly standard postdoc requirement - to be able to assess what you (or your group) needs to succeed (resources) and then use them effectively.

Basically, if your supervisor comes to you and asks "What do we need to get this done?", they want you to neither badly undershoot, nor overspend, and when you get those resources, to use them appropriately.

I'd discuss any experience you had with managing project requirements, seeing something through to completion that had a budget, or just being able to cogently talk about being able to assess your position's needs.